# Mavericks AppleScript count every desktop always returns 1

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mavericks

I've got a script taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/pipwerks/OS-X-Wallpaper-Changer) that is supposed to set the wallpaper of every desktop to a certain image depending on the time of day. (I have modified it from the original code to include more time ranges, issue shows in both versions)

The script attempts to count the number of desktops in order to change more than just the current desktop. It does this by first telling `System Events` the following

```
set theDesktops to a reference to every desktop
```

And then, in order to loop through every desktop, it does the following:

```
if ((count theDesktops) > 1) then
    repeat with x from 2 to (count theDesktops)
        --some code removed, see full code below
    end repeat
end if
```

The issues is that `count theDesktops` always returns a 1, no matter how many desktops there are, as seen in the following screenshot.

http://ss.kobitate.com/2013-12-28_0922_2.png

What can be done to fix this? Here is the full code

```
(*

Script by Philip Hutchison, April 2013
http://pipwerks.com
MIT license http://pipwerks.mit-license.org/

This script assumes:

1. You have a folder named "Wallpapers" in your Pictures folder
2. You have a subfolder named "Time of Day" in Wallpapers
3. You have six subfolders inside "Time of Day", with names that match the variables below. 
   * If you decide to use different folder names, you must change the variables to match the new folder names
4. You have images inside each folder

For example:
/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Pictures/Wallpapers/Time of Day/Afternoon Early/image.jpg

GeekTool can execute this script for you at specified intervals. Use this line in the command field:
osascript ~/Pictures/Wallpapers/Time\ of\ Day/wallpaper.scpt

*)


-- BEGIN USER CONFIGURATION

-- supply folder names
set morningEarly to "Morning Early"
set morningLate to "Morning Late"
set afternoonEarly to "Afternoon Early"
set afternoonLate to "Afternoon Late"
set eveningEarly to "Evening Early"
set eveningLate to "Evening Late"
set nightEarly to "Night Early"
set nightLate to "Night Late"

-- for multiple monitor support.
-- set to true to display the same image on all desktops, false to show unique images on each desktop
set useSamePictureAcrossDisplays to true

-- END USER CONFIGURATION



-- get current hour
set h to hours of (current date)

-- set default periodOfDay
set periodOfDay to nightLate

-- change value of periodOfDay based on current time
if (h > 6 and h < 8) then
    set periodOfDay to morningEarly
else if (h ≥ 8 and h < 10) then
    set periodOfDay to morningLate
else if (h ≥ 10 and h < 12) then
    set periodOfDay to afternoonEarly
else if (h ≥ 12 and h < 16) then
    set periodOfDay to afternoonLate
else if (h ≥ 16 and h < 18) then
    set periodOfDay to eveningEarly
else if (h ≥ 18 and h < 20) then
    set periodOfDay to eveningLate
else if (h ≥ 20 and h < 22) then
    set periodOfDay to nightEarly
else if (h ≥ 22) then
    set periodOfDay to nightLate
end if


-- helper function ("handler") for getting random image
on getImage(folderName)

    tell application "Finder"
        return some file of folder ("Pictures:Wallpapers:Time of Day:" & folderName) of home as text
    end tell

end getImage


tell application "Finder"

    -- wrapped in a try block for error suppression
    try

        -- determine which picture to use for main display
        set mainDisplayPicture to my getImage(periodOfDay)

        -- set the picture for additional monitors, if applicable
        tell application "System Events"

            -- get a reference to all desktops
            set theDesktops to a reference to every desktop

            -- handle additional desktops
            if ((count theDesktops) > 1) then

                -- loop through all desktops (beginning with the second desktop)
                repeat with x from 2 to (count theDesktops)

                    -- determine which image to use
                    if (useSamePictureAcrossDisplays is false) then
                        set secondaryDisplayPicture to my getImage(periodOfDay)
                    else
                        set secondaryDisplayPicture to my mainDisplayPicture
                    end if

                    -- apply image to desktop
                    set picture of item x of the theDesktops to secondaryDisplayPicture

                end repeat

            end if

        end tell

        -- set the primary monitor's picture
        -- due to a Finder quirk, this has to be done AFTER setting the other displays
        set desktop picture to mainDisplayPicture

    end try

end tell
```

**Edit:** Fixed an unrelated mistake I found in the code

Comment: I think "desktop" refers to an actual display

Comment: Ahh yes I see this now. Only way I can find to set the wallpaper of every desktop with AppleScript tabs through each desktop by simulating the keyboard shortcut... which won't work for me since this script will run every so often to check the time.

Comment: Yeah I fear there's no way to script that. May be someone else has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed now. I remember testing this when @KobiTate posted it.

I am now on 10.9.1 but not sure when it was fixed

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theDesktops to count of (a reference to every desktop)
     set theDesktops2 to count every desktop
end tell
log "count of (a reference to every desktop) = " & theDesktops
log "count every desktop = " & theDesktops2
```

Returns:

(*count of (a reference to every desktop) = 2*)

(*count every desktop = 2*)